# Postgres and Docker: Database error - role "username" does not exist

Tags: python, postgresql, macos, docker, containers

I'm trying to implement configure the postgres database of this [project](https://github.com/valentino-dicianni/MAADB-ProjectMeo/tree/master/code/postgresConfig) on MacOS, so I installed postgres, docker and I tried to run `docker-compose up -d` on this docker file:

```
version: "3"

services:
  maadb-ps-db:
    image: postgres:latest
    container_name: maadb-ps-db
    ports:
      - "5433:5432"
    env_file:
      - postgres.env
    volumes:
      - database-data:/usr/local/var/postgres

volumes:
  database-data:
```

Here I have the environment file with only this line:

```
POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD=trust
```

Then, I try to connect to the database through python and the following method:

```
def get_resources_sql():
conn = None
try:
    # read connection parameters
    params = config()

    # connect to the PostgreSQL server
    print('Connecting to the PostgreSQL database...')
    conn = psycopg2.connect(**params)

    # create a cursor
    cur = conn.cursor()

    # TODO

    # close the communication with the PostgreSQL
    cur.close()
except (Exception, psycopg2.DatabaseError) as error:
    print("Database ERROR: ", error)
finally:
    if conn is not None:
        conn.close()
        print('Database connection closed.')
```

Where the params are the following:

```
[postgresql]
host=localhost
port=5433
database=maadbsql
```

When I try to run the code I get the following error:

```
args {'host': 'localhost', 'port': '5433', 'database': 'maadbsql'}
Connecting to the PostgreSQL database...
Database ERROR:  FATAL:  role "username" does not exist
```

If I try to open the maadbsql database through `psql maadbsql` and check the permissions, this is what I get (I have only two users, "username" and "postgres"):

[image]

Am I missing something?

EDIT:

this is the log after running `docker-compose up`: [link](https://pastebin.com/RPQ4S7GT)

this is the log after shutting down: [link](https://pastebin.com/Ed7upcvX)

Comment: I have a few questions. You said your environment file contains only the `POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD` line, but then where does the `username` postgres user come from? And how does the `maadbsql` database get created? It seems as if there is some information missing. Additionally, the connection params in the Python code don't appear to specify a username.

Comment: @larsks I created the maadbsql database manually because I saw that in the configuration files it was required. About the username account, I think it has been created when I installed Postgres, it has the same name of my system account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're not creating your database appropriately. I would start by deleting your containers and volumes:

```
docker-compose down -v
```

The configure your environment file so that the postgres image will create a database and user for your application:

```
POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD=trust
POSTGRES_USER=maadbsql
POSTGRES_DB=maadbsql
```

With this change, I can run the following Python code successfully:

```
>>> import psycopg2
>>> conn = psycopg2.connect('dbname=maadbsql user=maadbsql host=localhost port=5433')
>>> cur = conn.cursor()
>>> cur.execute('create table example(id int, name text)')
>>> conn.commit()
>>> cur.execute('insert into example (id, name) values (%s, %s)', (1, 'alice'))
>>> conn.commit()
>>> cur.execute('select * from example')
>>> cur.fetchall()
[(1, 'alice')]
```

Comment: I'm still getting the error 'Database ERROR:  FATAL:  role "username" does not exist' even adding those lines in the environment file and in the connect function.

Comment: There is no user named `username` in this example. The user is named `maadbsql`. If you run the sample code I've included in this answer, what happens? Everything in this question runs correctly for me. Here's a complete session: https://asciinema.org/a/AS0wAdGPG4h8nYVk4fALjUyDH

Comment: I get the error I mentioned in the comment above. Another problem is that it looks like it is not creating the database, in fact I can't access maadbsql. This is the log I see in docker: https://imgur.com/a/i1k08L9

Comment: Can you update your question to include the output of running `docker-compose up` after (a) modifying your environment file as suggested and (b) running `docker-compose down -v`?

Comment: This is after updating your `postgres.env` file, right?  I do see a `CREATE DATABASE` in the docker logs, so it is creating *a* database. At this point, if you try `docker exec -it  maadb-ps-db  psql -U maadbsql -c '\l'`, does it fail, or does it provide a list of databases?

Comment: It gives me: psql: error: FATAL:  role "maadbsql" does not exist

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235427/discussion-between-larsks-and-fabio).